# What is the meaning of this phrase "Someone has less authority than you "?

Tags: phrase-meaning

A sidekick might be a work assistant, a best friend, or even a devoted dog that follows you to school every day. Sometimes this word signifies an imbalance of power, though; if you say, “This is my sidekick, Sarah," it implies that       . "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authority means:

```
noun
 1. the power or right to give orders, make decisions, and enforce obedience.
```

The paragraph in your question talks about a "sidekick".  This is a person that usually helps a "superhero".  Therefore, the phrase "Someone has less authority than you" means that the other person (e.g 'Someone', 'sidekick', 'Sarah', etc) has less power that you.